# Stuck at boot after OTA update

Tags: boot, htc, ota-update, htc-one

I just today updated my unlocked, rooted HTC One M7 as usual, by

- flashing the stock recovery
- rebooting and downloading / installing the system update

The update went over without any problems, but after the update completed, it did not complete the boot process any more. It's stuck at the boot-logo of htc, after displaying the carriers logo. Forcing it to shut down and go in to the bootloader works fine, aswell as opening the recovery (both the stock one, and the custom one [TWRP]). However, no matter how many times I try to reboot, no success.

Normally in this situation, I would obviously just restore a previously made Nandroid backup, but since I am asking this question, well, you guessed it.. I felt too comfortable with the process and skipped the step of creating one.

I am really, really hoping that there is a way to fix this issue without having to lose my data.

---

Some additional information;

- CID: VODAP110
- OS before update: 7.18.161.2 (Dito for stock recovery)
- OS after update: 7.18.161.21
- Unlocked and S-OFF
- H-BOOT: 1.61.0000
- RADIO: 4T.35.3218.16

(It is an m7_ul variant, so nothing un-standard there)

---

EDIT: Due to the necessity of me being able to use my phone I gave up and chose the easy way out -> recovery, through a nandroid backup a few months back. However, if someone still finds an answer to this, I am very happy to accept it, for future viewers.

Answer (score 1):

Just found this thread because I was looking for the changes the update did.

I can't give you an answer you are maybe looking for of how to fix this, but just a question before:
How long did you wait?

My phone is not rooted but I noticed, that it took really long until the boot was over (got stuck at the htc boot logo like yours too)

I was waiting a little bit for about 3 or 4 minutes and then went away. When I came back it was finished. But for sure it took longer than usually.

Hope this will help you maybe.

Greetings from germany

Comment: Sadly that was probably not the problem, I started the boot, then went cooking and eating, and after about 60 minutes still the same screen. Thank you though! Greetings from Switzerland

Answer (score -1):

You can either completely redownload completely stock rom and flash that, or better install a custom rom from xda.

In case you decide to go with custom rom (which are better than stock mostly), here's what you have to do->

1) Download any custom rom such as cyanogenmod.

2) Set up [ADB](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979).

3) Boot your phone into wtrp recovery and use this command in adb-> `adb push NameAndPathToTheRomYouDownloaded.zip /sdcard/`
This will put the custom rom into your sdcard.

4) Wipe system, data, cache, dalvic (no need to wipe internal storage).

5) Install zip and point it to zip in 3rd step in sdcard and flash it. Reboot.

If you want to use stock rom, then use google search and follow the methods of unrooting process, thats how stock roms are installed. But again, custom roms are mostly much better maintained and more stable. You can also first flash custom rom, since use of adb with that is easier, than follow unroot method and flash back to complete stock. I wish I could give you complete details about stock rom flashing, but I have never owned an htc and dont know how their flash tools/methods work for stock roms.

EDIT: Since you factory resetted, did that fix it? Often data before ota does cause problems so its always recommended to factory reset after ota, but that dirty data should never be the reason for a bootloop.

Comment: See edited post, I didn't factory reset, I used an older Nandroid backup I had made a few months ago, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Its ok ;) my method still applies though...